# how to get a non english character in tcl from sql query recordset

Tags: sql, unicode, tcl

I am trying to execute a select sql query via tcl script . But after executing the sql query via tcl script the recordset does not contain the non english character but non english character is present in my column value.

Table Name: Employee 
Column name: EmpGroup

```
EmpGroup
--------
TRT 1ª REGIÃO
ATTAR
```

The result after executing the query is like

```
EmpGroup
--------
TRT 1 REGIÃO
ATTAR
```

so the 'ª' character is missing in my recordset.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Column data type?

Comment: Looks like there's a problem in what encoding is used for those bits of text — Tcl is internally native-unicode — but there's quite a few bits and pieces between the DB table and the Tcl language front-end so we will need to know the DBMS, the exact column definition, and the SQL-access library you're using. Versions too. Also, I've seen databases where the encoding of the data within was just completely broken, with different encodings on different rows of the same table, so it is possible that your _real_ problem is broken data, alas… but we should double-check everything else first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select Convert(NVARCHAR,EmpGroup) from Table
```